# Passing class to constructor, when no such constructor exists. Why does it work?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm having a class that looks like:

```
class A {
public:
    A(float v) 
    { 
        A::v = v; 
    }
    float v;
    float set(float v) 
    {
        A::v = v;
        return v;
    }
    float get(float v) 
    {
        return A::v;
    }
};
```

Then I instantiate 2 objects of class A:

```
A* a = new A(1.0);
A* b = new A(*a);
```

Why are there no errors when my Class A doesn't have a constructor which takes a class A?

Comment: Aside: `get` takes an argument: `float get(float v) ` -- but that's not a common expectation/idiom.  You may want to change that.

Comment: Are you sure your book doesn't cover this?

Comment: Surprised the syntax highlighter has pulled up `set`. Ish

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What's the world coming to?

Comment: @Bathsheba An end. Slowly :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Why not dupe-hammer it? I'm sure we had a similar question yesterday too, although I can't find it right now...

Comment: @BrianCain Wouldn't do that if it was my own code. This was part of a quiz i took, so the passing of arguments was probably made to cause confusion when used in another part of the code (which is not included in the snippet) :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof I didn't do it because the answers here talk about how to get the behavior the OP wants, which isn't covered by the dupe.  I didn't want to unilaterally close it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler generates a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) for you:

> If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class.

You can make the copy constructor and assignment deleted and make the compiler not declare move assignment and constructor by declaring one of move constructor or assignment as deleted:

```
A(A&&) = delete; // Makes the class non-copyable and non-moveable.
```

Comment: Upvoted as it seems that I have plagiarised your snippet! (Feel free to include any bits from my answer too - this looks to me to be the best answer of the current crop).

Comment: Is there really no dupe that covers this? That's a lot of answers for a question I could swear I've seen yesterday...

Comment: @Bathsheba Yours is a rather rare beast `A(A const&&)`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Last edit and a wiki as promised. It's hardly "my" answer any more!

Answer (score 8):

It *does* have the copy constructor: the compiler has generated one for you.

If you want to disable that explicitly, then write

```
A(const A&) = delete;
```

in the class declaration; and using

```
A(A&&) = delete;
```

deletes *all* the *rule of five* functions, except the destructor.

Comment: The compiler still generates the assignment operator though.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Yup indeed, added the idiomatic way of dealing with that.

Comment: nitpick: destructor still generated

Comment: One more fix and I'll wiki this!

Answer (score 5):

An implicit copy constructor is generated by the Compiler, if you do not specify an own.

One further note:

Try

```
A a = 3.0f;
```

Conclusion: always mark constructors that take a single basic data type as `explicit`  ... unless you like the implicit conversion

Comment: "always mark constructors that take a single basic data type as explicit" ... unless you like the implicit conversion.

Comment: That advice is out of date; you need to mark multi-argument constructors explicit too to obviate initialisation using `{}`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd argue you're still less likely to want to `explicit` those, but it's possible

Comment: @BrianCain of course you are right. but in my expierence it is wanted rather seldom, maybe if you imeplement some number class that should behave transparently.